Sending histogram data to grafana from statsd library of python
We are using statsd library in python to send some metrics to grafana. I am struggling to send histograms to grafana.
We use statsd-exporter and victoria metrics data store for the metrics in grafana.
I added the mapping section as mentioned here.
In python code, i extended the statsd lib to send histograms. "h" here is sending only metric_sum and metric_count alone. I was expecting buckets to be sent for metric name as defined in the mapping. Can someone help me out here.
from statsd import StatsClient
class CustomStatsClient(StatsClient):
    def histogram(self, stat: str, value: float):
         histogram_message = f"{self.prefix}.{stat}:{value}|h"
         self._send(histogram_message)

    def _send(self, message: str):
         self._sock.sendto(message.encode(), (self.host, self.port))

Mentioned the things i tried in the above section.
